# Multiple line shell commands using Python commands module

Tags: python, gdal

I'm trying to write a Python function that transforms a given coordinate system to another using gdal. Problem is that I'm trying to execute the command as one string, but in shell,  I have to press enter before entering the coordinates.

```
x = 1815421
y = 557301

ret = []

tmp = commands.getoutput( 'gdaltransform -s_srs \'+proj=lcc +lat_1=34.03333333333333 
+lat_2=35.46666666666667 +lat_0=33.5 +lon_0=-118 +x_0=2000000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=GRS80 
+units=m +no_defs\' -t_srs epsg:4326 \n' + str(x) + ' ' + str(y) )
```

I tried it  using '\n', but that doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any reason why you dont call osr.CoordinateTransformation() from within Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you run `gdaltransform` by pressing Enter and the coordinates are read by the program itself from its stdin, not the shell:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['gdaltransform', '-s_srs', ('+proj=lcc ' 
    '+lat_1=34.03333333333333 ' 
    '+lat_2=35.46666666666667 '
    '+lat_0=33.5 '
    '+lon_0=-118 +x_0=2000000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=GRS80 '
    '+units=m +no_defs'), '-t_srs', 'epsg:4326'],
    stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True) # run the program
output = p.communicate("%s %s\n" % (x, y))[0] # pass coordinates
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from subprocess import *

c = 'command 1 && command 2 && command 3'
# for instance: c = 'dir && cd C:\\ && dir'

handle = Popen(c, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
print handle.stdout.read()
handle.flush()
```

If i'm not mistaken, the commands will be executed over a "session" and thus keeping whatever niformation you need in between the commands.

More correctly, using `shell=True` (from what i've been tought) is that it's supposed to be used if given a string of commands rather than a list. If you'd like to use a list suggestions are to do as follows:

```
import shlex
c = shlex.split("program -w ith -a 'quoted argument'")

handle = Popen(c, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
print handle.stdout.read()
```

And then catch the output, Or you could work with a open stream and use `handle.stdin.write()` but it's a bit tricky.

Unless you only want to execute, read and die, `.communicate()` is perfect, or just `.check_output(<cmd>)`

Good information n how `Popen` works can be found here (altho different topic): [python subprocess stdin.write a string error 22 invalid argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650216/python-subprocess-stdin-write-a-string-error-22-invalid-argument)

## Solution

Anyway, this *should* work (**you have to redirect STDIN** and STDOUT):

```
from subprocess import *

c = 'gdaltransform -s_srs \'+proj=lcc +lat_1=34.03333333333333 +lat_2=35.46666666666667 +lat_0=33.5 +lon_0=-118 +x_0=2000000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs\' -t_srs epsg:4326 \n' + str(x) + ' ' + str(y) + '\n'

handle = Popen(c, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
print handle.stdout.read()
handle.flush()
```